# How do I set automatic resize?

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV242.jpg)I have used AutoSize/FixedDialog/GrowAndShrink combo before to set Formsize depending on the label size responsible for printing the Queryresult out. In this case I have done everything in the same way but the Shrink part is not functioning at all.

The label is also set AutoSize. Maximum size is determined, to have only the height autosized.

I have checked ten times all of the properties human can set and the difference between the former Forms and the one I have problem with. The conclusion:No difference (Instead of two little things (margin size and minimum size)).

I use property window when is it possible, so I can not present any code to this question.

I would like to now what is wrong in my thinking or what shoud I do more. It is a good answer for me that: Forget about the property window! Code! You want to be a developer.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public class QuerySelection
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Query { get; set; }

        public QuerySelection(string name, string query)
        {
            Name = name;
            Query = query;

        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }

    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();

    }

    const string QueryText1 = "This is the short selection!";
    const string QueryText2 = "This is the middle-long selection!";
    const string QueryText3 = "This is the long selection!";

    const string Query1 = "short";
    const string Query2 = "middle-short";
    const string Query3 = "long";

    const string ErrorText = "Choose a query!";

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBoxQueries.Items.Add(new QuerySelection(QueryText1, Query1));
        comboBoxQueries.Items.Add(new QuerySelection(QueryText2, Query2));
        comboBoxQueries.Items.Add(new QuerySelection(QueryText3, Query3));
    }

    private void buttonSelectedQueryResult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        QuerySelection selectedItem = (QuerySelection)comboBoxQueries.SelectedItem;

        if(comboBoxQueries.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ErrorText);

        }
        else
        {
            labelResult.Text = selectedItem.Query;

        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What kind of UI technology do you use? Maybe WPF or Windows Forms? Can you post the code you currently have?

Comment: It is pretty hard to identify what you are talking about without any context or code.

Comment: Visual Studio Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3 / Microsoft.NET Framework Version 4.7.03056

Comment: I can past the code but in the code ther is no refference about the size of the Form.

Comment: That is  the IDE (2015) and .NET version, not which of the UI technologies you are using. Microsoft themselves have multiple UI (and web) frameworks with important differences between them. Which are you using? You probably picked either "WPF App" or "Windows Forms App" when creating the project.

Comment: Reproduce your problem in a small blank application with some dummy data. That should give you some code you can post, or if using the graphical editor tools, an annotated screenshot showing what you placed and where, how it did size it, and what you wanted.

Comment: I reproduced the problem as you suggested.